# Get members of class from class name

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class name (as a `String`), and I want to get all members and their types. I know I need to use reflection, but how?

For instance, if I have

```
class MyClass {
    Integer a;
    String b;
}
```

how do I get the types and names of `a` and `b`?

Comment: Have a look at the [Oracle reflection guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/index.html) with contains tutorials, guides, samples and links to the API doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the classes have already been loaded by the jvm, you can use the static method of Class called Class.forName(String className); and it will return you a handle to the reflections object.

you would do:

```
//get class reflections object method 1
Class aClassHandle = Class.forName("MyClass");

//get class reflections object method 2(preferred)
Class aClassHandle = MyClass.class;

//get a class reflections object method 3: from an instance of the class
MyClass aClassInstance = new MyClass(...);
Class aClassHandle = aClassInstance.getClass();



//get public class variables from classHandle
Field[] fields = aClassHandle.getFields();

//get all variables of a class whether they are public or not. (may throw security exception)
Field[] fields = aClassHandle.getDeclaredFields();

//get public class methods from classHandle
Method[] methods = aClassHandle.getMethods();

//get all methods of a class whether they are public or not. (may throw security exception)
Method[] methods = aClassHandle.getDeclaredMethods();

//get public class constructors from classHandle
Constructor[] constructors = aClassHandle.getConstructors();

//get all constructors of a class whether they are public or not. (may throw security exception)
Constructor[] constructors = aClassHandle.getDeclaredConstructors();
```

To get a variable named b from MyClass, one might do.

```
Class classHandle = Class.forName("MyClass");
Field b = classHandle.getDeclaredField("b");
```

and if b is type integer, to get its value i would do.

```
int bValue = (Integer)b.get(classInstance);//if its an instance variable`
```

or

```
int bValue = (Integer)b.get(null);//if its a static variable
```

Comment: Assume that i dont know the field type how should I do it ? you are doing int bValue = (Integer)b.get(classInstance); but I have list of the class members(Im using Field[] fields = classHandle.getDeclaredFields();) and I want to know the respective type. I cant use your code since you are doing casting and I dont know the field type

Comment: if you have some Field f, and you want to get a class handle to its type, you use f.getType(); you can also just change it to Object bValue = b.get(...);

Comment: also, if the field is not public, you will have to call field.setAccessible(true); before the get, or you will get a security exception

Answer (score 1):

First get the class:

```
Class clazz=ClassforName("NameOfTheClass")
```

Than ask for all other information
[Class API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)